# TensorFlow Slim Pre-trained models Negative Dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to design a wrapper to use the pre-made tensorflow slim models for a custom dataset. the dataset is 1000 images of squares and triangles, 32x32 grayscale. They are organized as dataset/shapes/triangles/ and dataset/shapes/squares/.

Using the following code, I am able to train the inception_v2 model without errors. The tf.reshape will be replaced with the correct variable parameters later. The .tfrecords files are created using [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py) script from google that creates the records from the above mentioned dataset structure.

```
graph = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=graph)

with graph.as_default():
    name_dict, nClass = gen_dict(data_directory, path_to_labels_file)

    # associate the "label" and "image" objects with the corresponding features read from
    # a single example in the training data file
    label, image = getImage("datasets/shapes/train-00000-of-00001", height, width, nClass)

    # associate the "label_batch" and "image_batch" objects with a randomly selected batch---
    # of labels and images respectively
    imageBatch, labelBatch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [image, label], batch_size=bsize,
        capacity=2000,
        min_after_dequeue=1000)

    with sess.as_default():
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        batch_xs, batch_ys = sess.run([imageBatch, labelBatch])

        print('ran shuffle batch')
        print(tf.shape(batch_xs))
        print(tf.shape(batch_ys))
        # batch_xs = tf.expand_dims(batch_xs, 2)
        batch_xs = tf.reshape(batch_xs, [100, 32, 32, 1])
        print(tf.shape(batch_xs))
        logits, end_points = inception.inception_v2(batch_xs,
                                                    num_classes=2,
                                                    is_training=True)

        predictions = end_points['Predictions']
        logits = end_points['Logits']

        tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(batch_ys, logits)

        total_loss = slim.losses.get_total_loss()

        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=.001)

        train_tensor = slim.learning.create_train_op(total_loss, optimizer)

        slim.learning.train(train_tensor,
                            train_log_dir,
                            number_of_steps=1000)
```

The issue I'm having is with other models. Using inception_v1, with the same arguments, I get the following error:

```
File "model_test.py", line 62, in <module>
    is_training=True)
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/inception_v1.py", line 349, in inception_v1
    net, [7, 7], stride=1, scope='MaxPool_0a_7x7')
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 131, in avg_pool2d
    outputs = layer.apply(inputs)
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 492, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 441, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/pooling.py", line 276, in call
    data_format=utils.convert_data_format(self.data_format, 4))
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1741, in avg_pool
    name=name)
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 48, in _avg_pool
    data_format=data_format, name=name)
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2508, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1873, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1823, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
  File "/home/chakicherla3/tf_slim_image_classification/models/slim/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 676, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 7 from 1 for 'InceptionV1/Logits/MaxPool_0a_7x7/AvgPool' (op: 'AvgPool') with input shapes: [100,1,1,1024].
```

I get a similar error using inception_v3. With vgg_16 and vgg_19, I get:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 7 from 1 for 'vgg_16/fc6/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [100,1,1,512], [7,7,512,4096].
```

Can anyone give insight into these errors? What could be the difference between inception_v1 and inception_v2 that would cause it to crash, and how are the inception models this different? I haven't tried this dataset with ResNet yet, but I suspect a similar error will happen with that as well.

For reference, this example code is based on the 'working example' provided with the tf slim documentation, located [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim#working-example-training-the-vgg16-model)

The system it is running on is using Python 2.7.10 with Tensorflow-GPU 1.2.0. It's a Xeon system with 4 Nvidia Titan X GPUs, on Ubuntu 14.10.

Thanks! If you need any additional system configurations or the getImage function I can provide those as well!

Comment: The problem is the input size. For example, VGG network works only for 224x224.

Comment: Thanks @vijaym. Do you know why inception v2 is working with this data but not the others? If the size is the requirement shouldn't v2 also be throwing an error?

Answer (score 1):

Input images with size 32x32 too small for inception model. Inception_v1 try to use average pooling with kernel size 7x7, but on input to this layer came 1x1 data (with 1024 channels) after all previous pooling layers.

Anyway i think "inception" is too big for task, which you describe.

Comment: Is it possible to use the tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad function to pad all of the images to the correct sizes for each model? Would that degrade the quality of the model? I'm just using the squares/triangles model as a placeholder for any other data that may be used in the future.

Comment: If you plan work with only two class and image 32 x 32. then inception model is too much for this. You can try model with few (two or three) convolution+relu+maxpool chains. Good example is [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn)

Comment: My program isn't for specifically this dataset, I'm just using it as a placeholder for future custom datasets. The program is specifically supposed to use those models (inception, resnet, vgg, etc.) from the TF Slim Image classification library, and allow people with limited experience using these models to easily load in their own data and train.

Comment: Not all models can be used for arbitrary input image size. For example, [inception_v1 implementation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/inception_v1.py) in tf.slim requires input images with size 224 x 224, because this line of code:
`net = layers_lib.avg_pool2d(net, [7, 7], stride=1, scope='MaxPool_0a_7x7')`

Comment: But for example [inception_v2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/inception_v2.py) doesn't, because it can setup size of feature map by this:
`kernel_size = _reduced_kernel_size_for_small_input(net, [7, 7])`

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. is there a way to scale the images up from 32x32 to 224x224 or whatever the default size is for another model?

Comment: You can use (tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad)[https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_image_with_crop_or_pad] on the input, but i think this will really strange from my point of view.